# It's okay to download an XML with browser, but not with downloaders like wget

Tags: archiving, web, filetype

The link is https://api.bilibili.com/x/v1/dm/list.so?oid=162677333. When I download it with wget I get a binary file, and I thought it would be GZIP or deflate, which is often the web request case, but it is not.

What is this file?

For convenience - since we don't have wget handy sometimes - the file can be found here, with filename `unknown`: https://github.com/ggaarder/snippets/raw/master/unknown

Answer (score 0):

You can check the file type by inspecting the HTTP headers. Use wget's -S option

```
$ wget -S https://api.bilibili.com/x/v1/dm/list.so?oid=162677333
--2020-07-28 19:06:43--  https://api.bilibili.com/x/v1/dm/list.so?oid=162677333
Resolving api.bilibili.com (api.bilibili.com)... 148.153.34.154, 148.153.35.66
Connecting to api.bilibili.com (api.bilibili.com)|148.153.34.154|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 18:05:29 GMT
  Content-Type: text/xml
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  Bili-Trace-Id: 1a2ebdf95f2069
  Content-Encoding: deflate
  Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Jul 2020 02:06:45 GMT
  X-Robots-Tag: noindex
  Set-Cookie: bfe_id=f197415d50c3ae88d0c168156836d178; Path=/; Max-Age=600; Expires=Tue, 28-Jul-20 18:15:29 GMT
  Expires: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 18:05:28 GMT
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  X-Cache-Webcdn: BYPASS from cds-euwest-webcdn-02
Length: unspecified [text/xml]
Saving to: ‘list.so?oid=162677333’
```

Note the two headers

```
  Content-Type: text/xml
  Content-Encoding: deflate
```

So XML that is encoded using the [`deflate` algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE)

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at the header.

Comment: Thank you, I made it. It's not the header, the data is good just the downloaders can't decode it. It is something between deflate, zlib and gzip. I don't know. But I can decode it now.

Comment: Yes in fact I saw this at the very beginning, but the file can't be opened by my archive manager, so I thought it was broken. I took a tortuous course.

Answer (score 0):

It is something between deflate, zlib and gzip. I don't know. But I can decode it now.

Just use `zlib` to decompress it, with `inflateInit2(&strm, -MAX_WBITS)` instead of `inflateInit(&strm)`.

Comment: Why was this submitted as an answer?